# Create a loop within r to sum total of particular rows of column

Tags: r, loops

Apologise in advance - I am a beginner

I have a cvs file that I have loaded into R (See data)
[image]

I am trying to create a 'summary' dataframe to show the total new cases for weeks 21-24 and weeks 37-41 (Dont need this by country, just an overall figure for both week periods).
I was thinking of doing this by creating a loop to check the content of the "year_week" column in the main data and i.e if "2020-W21" add the data in the new_cases column to a vector and if not add to an alternative vector. I am however stuck how to write this loop.

Any help much appreciated, Many Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't need a loop for it. For data manipulation I recommend that you have a look at [`dplyr`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/)

Comment: I think the new question is just a dupe of your previous question.  You need to remove the 'country' from the group_by

Comment: Thanks-Is there a way to also do this using a loop to loop through the year_weeks column i.e if "2020-W21" add content of the newcases column to a vector which sums the total?